# How to update my UIButton Background colour to specific colour code 0xff64b5f6

Tags: ios, background-color, uicolor

I have a new spec for my app which requires the changing of the background buttons to specific colours provided as colour codes, ie: 0xff64b5f6.

I've been browsing and cannot find any alternative the doesn't use the redColor, blueColor etc.

I also tried using UIColorFromRGB(0xff64B5F6) which returns an integer instead of UIColor.

There must be a solution if anyone can help.

I'm using Xcode6 with IOS8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own:

```
@implementation UIColor (HexCodes)

+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexRed:(Byte)red green:(Byte)green blue:(Byte)blue alpha:(Byte)alpha
{
    return [self colorWithRed:red / 255.0 green:green / 255.0 blue:blue / 255.0 alpha:alpha / 255.0];
}

@end
```

Then call it:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorFromHexRed:0xff green:0x64 blue:0xB5 alpha:0xF6];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your color appears to have an alpha component as well as RGB, try the following macro:

```
#define UIColorFromRGBA(rgbValue) \
[UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)(((rgbValue) & 0xFF000000) >> 24))/255.0 \
                green:((CGFloat)(((rgbValue) & 0x00FF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                 blue:((CGFloat)(((rgbValue) & 0x0000FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
                alpha:((CGFloat)(((rgbValue) & 0x000000FF) >>  0))/255.0]
```

You can re-order the statements based on whether your color is RGBA, or ARGB.